# order of loading files in the header of magento

Tags: magento2.3.5-p2

I need help, whenever I reload the cart page, some things don't load, and when I click on the file upload order it seems to fix but other things stop working, I think the content is in the wrong order, can someone help me? help ? follows an example from my code.

```
 <css src="mage/calendar.css"/>
        <script src="mage/polyfill.js"/>
        
        <css src="css/bootstrap.css"/>
        <css src="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
        
        <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"/>
        <script src="requirejs/require.js"/>

        <css rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.1/css/all.css"  src_type="url"/>
```

Comment: I don't think `upload order` is a native function of Magento. Are you using a custom extension or theme? In that case, you will have to contact the extension/theme builder to debug.

Comment: if it is true what you are saying then move require js file to the top.